# saveField does not update the record

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am unable to update a particular field in CakePHP. Below the following code. When you run the `$this->OrdemServico->saveField()`, simply it does not work.

```
class OrdemServico extends AppModel {

public $name = "OrdemServico";
public $useTable = "ordens_servico";
public $belongsTo = array(
    "Cliente" => array(
        "className" => "Cliente",
        "foreignKey" => "id_cliente"
    ),
    "Responsavel" => array(
        "className" => "Usuario",
        "foreignKey" => "responsavel"
    ),
    "Equipamento" => array(
       "className" => "Equipamento",
       "foreignKey" => "equipamento"
    ),
    "ModoEntrega" => array(
       "className" => "ModoEntrega",
       "foreignKey" => "modo_entrega"
    )
);

}


class OrdemServicoController extends AppController {
 public function cancelar() {
    try {
        $this->layout = "ajax";
        $this->autoLayout = false;

        $data = $this->request->data;
        $id = $data["question"]["parameter"];
        $destino = unserialize($data["question"]["callback"]);

        $this->OrdemServico->id = $id;
        $this->OrdemServico->saveField("OrdemServico.cancelado", true);

        $this->Dialog->alert("A ordem de serviço foi cancelada com sucesso.");
        $this->redirect($destino);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $mensagem = "Ocorreu um erro no sistema ao atualizar a ordem de serviço.";

        $this->Dialog->error($mensagem, $ex->getMessage());
        $this->redirect(array("action" => "index"));
   }
}
```

}

```
question.ctp
<div id="dialog-question" class="modal-dialog">
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    "url" => array(
        "controller" => "ordem_servico",
        "action" => "cancelar"),
    "id" => $form_name,
    "role" => "form"
));

echo $this->Form->hidden("question.parameter");
echo $this->Form->hidden("question.callback", array("value" => serialize($retorno)));
?>

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="cursor: move">
        <button id="btn-question-close" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sistema de Ordem de Serviço</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?= h($message) ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btn-cancel-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><?= $buttons["cancel"] ?></button>
        <button id="btn-default-modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><?= $buttons["ok"] ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I wonder what's going on because the system can not update any fields this way.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages and have you checked the SQL query generated by `saveField()`?

Comment: Having functions that do something like "cancel" work by GET requests is not a good design. You're risking creating empty records with `cancelado = 1` with your current code.

Comment: No error is generated in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### saveField expects a field name

> `$this->OrdemServico->saveField("OrdemServico.cancelado", true);`

[saveField](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.1/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1680-L1704) does not expect a model-prefixed field name. The above syntax is equivalent to calling:

```
$this->OrdemServico->save([
    'OrdemServico' => [
        'id' => x,
        'OrdemServico.cancelado' => true
    ]
]);
```

That won't work.

To use saveField, just pass it a field name:

```
$this->OrdemServico->saveField("cancelado", true);
```

Or, call save.

Comment: Error generated: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ordemservico`.`ordens_servico`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ordens_servico_usuarios` FOREIGN KEY (`responsavel`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Thanks. The problem was attributed parameter in the wrong way